# How to write letters with beginPath in the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'd like to know if there's any data for drawing letters ? I don't want to use "fillText" function because i need the coordinates to do things in the red zone. I thought i'd use the ready-made coordinates to build a table with the coordinates that are inside the letter itself and out. Does my gait seem right to you ?

[image: letter A]

I want to build this kind of thing: https://36days.reflektor.digital/letter/A with all the letters of the alphabet.

Thank you.

Comment: You can draw a big black letter on a secondary canvas and use its `imageData` to find out if a pixel is part of the letter or not; just check the value for the red channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If raster coordinates of the letter/text are enough (i.e. that you don't need the actual vector instructions required to draw each glyph):

- `fillText` your text in e.g. white or black, e.g. onto a secondary canvas/context
- Grab a snapshot with [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)
- Depending on what you're doing in the end,

  - either sample random pixels from the snapshot,
  - or iterate over it once to find all the opaque pixels into e.g. a set or array

## Example

Based on OP's https://jsfiddle.net/3apm6d70/ here is a full example of what I mean.

- `renderTextToPixelList()` measures and renders a font onto a canvas (and doesn't clear it).
- Once we have the pixel list, we set up an interval function to randomly select a pixel from the list and draw it with another color, so we end up with an animation of the text appearing and slowly changing color.

```js
async function loadFonts() {
  const font = new FontFace("Alfa Slab One", "url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/092d2fc4b6fd921ba340df3151fe4aa3.woff2)");
  await font.load();
  document.fonts.add(font);
}

function renderTextToPixelList(font, text, canvas, sampleStep = 3) {
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  const measurements = context.measureText(text);
  const width = Math.ceil(measurements.width);
  const height = Math.ceil(measurements.actualBoundingBoxAscent - measurements.actualBoundingBoxDescent);
  context.fillText(text, measurements.actualBoundingBoxLeft, height);
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  const opaquePixels = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y += sampleStep) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += sampleStep) {
      const off = y * width * 4 + x * 4 + 3; // Offset to alpha channel
      if (imageData.data[off] > 240) {
        opaquePixels.push([x, y]);
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    opaquePixels,
    width,
    height,
  };
}

function drawDot(context, pmap) {
  const idx = Math.floor(pmap.opaquePixels.length * Math.random());
  let [x, y] = pmap.opaquePixels[idx];
  x *= 1.5;
  y *= 1.5;
  const hue = (x + 5 + +new Date() / 150) % 360;
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = `hsla(${hue}, 100%, 50%, 0.5)`;
  context.ellipse(x - 1, y - 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 6.283);
  context.fill();
}

loadFonts().then(() => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const pmap = renderTextToPixelList("100px Alfa Slab One", "Hello", canvas);
  canvas.width = canvas.width + 0; // clear canvas
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  setInterval(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) drawDot(context, pmap);
  }, 20);
});
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello, I'm stuck centering the letter and taking the capture. What am I missing? Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/3apm6d70/

Comment: @Jimmy.D I added a full example :)

Comment: Thank you I started again with your indications, here is where I blocked, I think that my capture (getImageData) doesn't go very well and I don't understand why, I drew everything on the screen to help me.

I don't understand at all in the loop what are the magic values to find the offset (const off). Can you enlighten me about this please? :) https://jsfiddle.net/xt47bhgu/1/

Comment: I finally got it to work. Even though I didn't understand the constant "off". This way of doing things frightens me a bit because it is very heavy in terms of performance. If you increase the font size it's a sure crash of the browser. https://jsfiddle.net/3nr182sh/

Comment: If you increase the font size, you'll also want to increase `sampleStep`. Also remember you can sample the font at a smaller size and resolution, then draw it at a higher one. Also, unless the text, font or size changes, don't re-sample it every frame!

Comment: Regarding `off`, since `imageData.data` is an array of height x width x RGBA (4) pixels, `off = (y * width * 4) + (x * 4)` is the formula to get the R channel at (X, Y); add 3 to that to skip over G and B to get to A.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the longest is the treatment of opaque pixels, how is it possible to save their positions with a small font and increase the size afterwards? The positions won't be good anymore. Thank you for your time.

Comment: My example already plots the pixels with `x *= 1.5; y *= 1.5;`, i.e. scales the original up by 50%.